# Google Hangouts iOS application URL schemes

Tags: url-scheme, google-hangouts

The url schema for Google drive is googledrive:// , Similar to this i need Hang outs Schema. I want to open Google hangout app from native code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 com.google.hangouts://
```

I found that above schema will work for Hangouts

Comment: Thanks it worked, and i found url schema for other API's


-

MicroSoft Outlook  : ms-outlook://
Google Drive :          googledrive://
Google Docs:           googledocs://
Google Calender:    googlecalendar://
Google Mail:            googlegmail://

Comment: WHERE do you found that!?

Comment: The com.google.hangouts: scheme URL doesn't seem to be registered by the current Hangouts app :-(

Comment: Hey. This URL scheme didn't work for me. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how start:

*Chat*

`com.google.hangouts://textchat?p=g[ID_USER]`

*Video*

`com.google.hangouts://textchat?p=g[ID_USER]`

Comment: can you please, write an example. what I am trying is com.google.hangouts://textchat?p=g[example@gmail.com] is this the way we should compose url.

Comment: Need to be the ID, you need integrate with google API to request an user ID. It's too hard :(